# Rspec not creating .rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Running through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  In section 3.2.1 upon running the generate command, I get an invoke response **but not the expected create response**:

```
$ rails generate integration_test static_pages
  invoke  rspec
```

I can create the expected /requests/static_pages_spec.rb file simply enough but I would like to understand why I am not getting the expected output as shown in the tutorial:

```
$ rails generate integration_test static_pages
  invoke  rspec
  create    spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Here is my gemfile for added reference:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :mri_21, :rbx]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.1'
end
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.2'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

Edit: Adding code from the application.rb file as suggested in a comment below.  Code formatting in comments is evading me...

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec,
    fixtures: true,
    view_specs: false,
    helper_specs: false,
    routing_specs: false,
    controller_specs: false,
    request_specs: false
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

I did some google mining but didn't have much luck finding a good overview of all the possible options g.test_framework method. Not sure if that is where the issue lies or not.

Edit 2:  Adding for others who may have the same question - The app was generated using rails-composer https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/ I am assuming that this is a auto configured setting as part of the setup.

Comment: maybe stupid question, but is the file already in your spec folder?

Comment: Nope, nothing is created.  I can do it manually and it works fine but my main concern is the "Why?" I would call myself an advanced newbie.  I know a little but when things don't go like I plan, I really want to know what happened to cause the change in expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I should think if you change the `false` value to `true` for `request_specs`, things will work for you.

```
config.generators do |g| 
  g.test_framework :rspec, 
    fixtures: true, 
    view_specs: false, 
    helper_specs: false, 
    routing_specs: false, 
    controller_specs: false, 
    request_specs: false #change this one! 
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories" 
end
```

Comment: Boom, that got the expected output!  Thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly install rspec-rails? `rails generate rspec:install`

If you did, make sure in `config/application.rb` you have something like:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :haml
  g.test_framework  :rspec, fixture_replacement: :factory_girl
  g.factory_girl dir: 'fixtures/factories'
end
```

in there

Comment: @Khundawg, you should edit your original question and add this information there.  It's difficult to read in a comment, and new viewers will likely not see it.